# Swapped 2 accounts domains on WHM, now both no longer work

Tags: domains, web-hosting, cpanel, whm

I have 2 accounts with websites on my VPS - one had an old website, the other I was developing a new website on.

When I had finished the new website I simply went to 'Modify Accounts' and swapped the Domain Names fields of both accounts, so that the new account had the old accounts domain name and vice versa.

Now neither site works - I just get the standard CPanel `defaultwebpage.cgi` place holder.

Have I missed something? Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you! Someone will. Can your host tech support help you?

Comment: Does [this page help](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/change-a-domain-name-in-cpanelwhm/)?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean you have 2 accounts with websites no my VPS? Do you mean on your VPS you have two domains hosted, through two cPanel accounts created in WHM?

I would first backup all files and databases. Then go in with SSH and look to see what folders the files are in and review apache's global and site configuration files to see what happened when you made the switch in WHM.

You can use easy apache to rebuild the configuration file. Then recreate the accounts individually and upload the files and import databases for each domain.

In the future when you work on a development server (domain) which you want to migrate to the products / live server instead of messing with WHM settings just overwrite the live files after you've made backups.